# add color to content c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this Code from my XAML.CS

```
 InitializeComponent();
        this.question = answers;
        this.list_question.ItemsSource = answers;
        int num_of_questions = this.question.Count;
        int ps = num_of_questions/2;

        label_score.Content = Convert.ToString(ca) + " / " +    Convert.ToString(num_of_questions);

        if (ca >= ps)
        {
            label_result.Content = "Passed!!"; 
        }
        else
        {
            label_result.Content = "Failed!!";
        }
```

How can i put color that if the result is "Passed" the textcolor will be Blue and if the result is FAILED..the text color is red will be displayed in my XAML form? 
Im using WPF application in C#.:) THANKS.>^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Foreground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
if (ca >= ps)
{
    label_result.Content = "Passed!!"; 
    label1.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
}
else
{
    label_result.Content = "Failed!!";
    label1.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

When you're just starting out, it's easier to use code-behind. But you'll definitely want to learn about data binding and the MVVM pattern sooner rather than later. You can find a lot of excellent resources online, such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial). *(randomly picked from top google results, but both rated well)*

Comment: Thanks it work.xD
Im using databinding in my project today but im just new in c#.
And thanks for the resources..this will give me more knowledge..

Comment: if you are implementing for the first time then also it is always preferred that you set styling in the XAML file itself rather then in coding, this will save you many efforts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can add trigger like below

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Content"  Value="Passed">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Content"  Value="Failed">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LabelStyle}" Content="Failed" />
    </Grid>
```